# docker - published port not available?

Tags: docker, tcp, portforwarding

I have a ubu18-based container that runs our custom application that sends out ~100 bytes of binary data once every second on tcp port 41001.

If I start the container like this:
`$ docker run --net=host my_container`

Then I can test it by using telnet:
`$ telnet 127.0.0.1 41001`
and I see a burst of characters on the terminal once per second.

However, if I start the container like this:
`$ docker run -p 0.0.0.0:41001:41001 my_container`

Then when I telnet as above, I get a connection followed by an immediate disconnection (no data).

In both methods of running, I can see the port 41001 open for listening by using `netstat -a`. We also see the 41001 port being listed as forwarded properly in the VSCode Ports window.

I've tried many things after the `-p` flag, such as `127.0.0.1:41001:41001` and just `41001:41001`, but none make any difference in behavior.

Further, it works just fine to use a pre-built toy container like strm/helloworld-http. In this case the port 80 gets forwarded and can be connected using the bridge network.

We've tested our above 41001 problem on multiple PCs, on Windows, native-ubuntu22.04, WSL2, and the behavior as described above is the same everywhere.

What are we missing? How do we set up port forwarding to work in our case?
Thanks!

Comment: What does the listener look like in your code?  If it's set to listen on 127.0.0.1:41001, in a container with normal Docker networking, that will listen only on the container-private localhost interface, and it won't be reachable from outside the container, even via published port.  That seems consistent with the symptoms you describe.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful in helping find the cause. We actually don't have access to the code for the socket opening and listening in our actual application. But, I wrote a simpler test app, and I can reproduce the issue by binding the listening socket to INADDR_LOOPBACK instead of INADDR_ANY. We'll talk to the vendor that supplied the application about what can be done. Thanks!